# asp.net requests queued even when #threads, requests/sec is low

Tags: asp.net, performance

We have an asp.net 4.0 (integrated mode) web application that runs on iis 7.5 x64 (w2k8) with 12 GB ram and 16 cores that has problem with spikes of requests queued. Normally the queue is zero, but occasionally (probably aroud 15 times over a 10 minute period) the queue spikes up to about 20-100 in the queue.

Sometimes this queue also correlate with a higher number of requests/sec. But that isn't always the case.
Requests current seems to always be between 15-30.

nbr of current logical and physical threads is as low as 60-100

CPU load is avg of 6%

requests/sec is around 150-200

connections active seems to be slowly increasing. It's about 7000.
connections established seems faily consitent around 130-140.

Since we are running .net 4.0 in integrated mode I suppose that we should be able to handle up to 5000 simultanously requests, or atleast 1000 (http.sys kernel)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/07/21/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-0-and-6-0.aspx

What could be causing .net to queue the requests even though there are threads left and requests/sec is low?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess:  Garbage collection suspends all threads, so perhaps the period immediately following the garbage collection would look like a request spike, since IIS would be piling up requests during the GC.  Can you correlate the spikes with garbage collections? If your application is I/O-bound, it may not be possible to drive the CPU load very high, since the threads will spend most of their time blocked.

The apparent leak of active connections is disturbing though, if it really is ever-increasing.

Comment: NOTE: .NET 4.5 has since made garbage collection asynchronous